# Is setTimeout safe for scheduling jobs over large spans of time?

Tags: javascript, node.js, timer

I'm writing an application in Node.js that needs to schedule functions to be run at specific times. Hours or sometimes days in the future. Currently, I'm doing so with something similar to this:

```
const now = Date.now();
const later = getSomeFutureTimestamp();
setTimeout(function() {
  // do something
}, later - now);
```

I'm wondering if `setTimeout` is the proper tool for this job or if there is a tool more suited for long intervals of time. One thing to note is I don't need great precision; if the job runs within a few minutes of the scheduled time, everything should still be fine.

Comment: This should probably be moved to SO, the question isn't really about code review

Comment: You may find better luck using an external application for this such as Redis. While you can keep timers in JavaScript, it's not exactly scalable beyond a single instance for obvious reasons. A great library in NodeJS for this sort of thing is [kue](https://www.npmjs.com/package/kue), which uses Redis under the hood. In particular, see [Delayed Jobs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/kue#delayed-jobs).

Comment: @Jonah I wasn't sure. The question is more about good practice than fixing issues, so I figured code review made more sense.

Comment: @SimpleJ broken = stack. Working, but could be improved = code review. Conceptual/theoretical = programmers. I'd say if you're asking about a specific problem (which you're facing), SO is a better place. CR is more for reviewing your app once its done than helping you with design decisions.

Comment: @DanPantry I only need a single job scheduled at any given time, and I likely won't need any of the many features kue has, so I think I'm going to stick with `setTimeout`. Thank you for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`setTimeout` should be fine. It's only really delayed if there's blocking code running at the moment when it's meant to execute. So `setTimeout` is typically 20 *milliseconds* late. But since your margin is minutes, I don't think it'll be an issue.

However, I'd suggest storing the timestamp at which things should trigger, and just periodically check. That way you only have 1 timer running at any given time.

You also get to keep your timestamps as absolute timestamps - not as relative, "milliseconds in the future" values. That also lets you store them between server restarts, which you can't do as easily with relative times. With your code, the only record of a job being queued is that there's a timer running. If that timer disappears for any reason, you lose all record of a job having been scheduled.

Something like:

```
function checkForScheduledJobs() {
  var now = Date.now(),
      job;

  // assuming here that the jobs array is sorted earliest to latest
  while(jobs.length && jobs[0].timestamp < now) {
    jobs.shift().callback();
  }

  setTimeout(checkForScheduledJobs, 60000); // check each minute
}
```

You just need to kick it off once. This could be done in an `addScheduledJob` function (which would also sort the `jobs` array after adding something to it, etc.)